# Getting the following error while running 'pip install web3' command

Tags: python, pip

I ran the command

```
pip install web3
```

and got the following error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\kashy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m2poz8gm\\cytoolz_aca0ceb4e0dd49da9c9b73d162a22e9f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\kashy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m2poz8gm\\cytoolz_aca0ceb4e0dd49da9c9b73d162a22e9f\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\kashy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-350ycn7k\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\kashy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Include\cytoolz'
         cwd: C:\Users\kashy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m2poz8gm\cytoolz_aca0ceb4e0dd49da9c9b73d162a22e9f\
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\kashy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m2poz8gm\\cytoolz_aca0ceb4e0dd49da9c9b73d162a22e9f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\kashy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m2poz8gm\\cytoolz_aca0ceb4e0dd49da9c9b73d162a22e9f\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\kashy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-350ycn7k\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\kashy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Include\cytoolz' Check the logs for full command output.
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+or+greater+is+required

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+windows+web3

Answer (score 2):

You probably need Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater version.

Comment: How do I do that?